# $\limsup$ inequality: $\limsup (a_n/b_n) \leqslant \limsup (a_{n+1} - a_n)/(b_{n+1}-b_n)$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm working on a question from a practice final and keep hitting dead ends. The question is:

> Let $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ and $(b_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be sequences in $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose that $(b_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is increasing with $\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = + \infty$. Prove that
> $\lim \sup_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} \leq \lim \sup_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}-b_n}$.
> (Hint: Let $\lim \sup_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}-b_n} < l$ with $l \in \mathbb{R}$. Then ...)

In our course, we have studied the sum inequality for lim sup and lim inf, but not the inequalities relating to products or reciprocals. I've tried playing around with product and reciprocal inequalities anyway, but I'm not sure I can use them when $\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = + \infty$.

We also covered the following inequality:
$\lim \inf_{n \to \infty} \lvert \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \rvert \leq \lim \inf_{n \to \infty} {\lvert a_n \rvert}^{\frac{1}{n}} \leq \lim \sup_{n \to \infty} {\lvert a_n \rvert}^{\frac{1}{n}} \leq \lim \sup_{n \to \infty} \lvert \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \rvert$

I thought this could be useful, but I'm not sure how to apply it.

Thank you for any hints or feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $l=\limsup_{n}\frac{a_{n+1}-a_{n}}{b_{n+1}-b_{n}}$. If $l=+\infty$,
we are done. Suppose that $l<+\infty$. Firstly, consider the case
that $l\neq-\infty$, i.e., $l\in\mathbb{R}$. Let $\varepsilon>0$
be arbitrary, then there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{a_{n+1}-a_{n}}{b_{n+1}-b_{n}}<l+\varepsilon$
whenever $n\geq N$. Note that since $\limsup_{n}\frac{a_{n+1}-a_{n}}{b_{n+1}-b_{n}}$
is well-defined and $b_{n+1}-b_{n}\geq0$, we must have $b_{n+1}-b_{n}>0$
for sufficiently large $n$ (otherwise, the denominator of $\frac{a_{n+1}-a_{n}}{b_{n+1}-b_{n}}$
is zero for infinitely many $n$, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sup_{k\geq n}\frac{a_{k+1}-a_{k}}{b_{k+1}-b_{k}}$
is undefined). Without loss of generality, we may assume that $b_{n+1}-b_{n}>0$ and $b_n>0$ (because $b_n\rightarrow +\infty$)
whenever $n\geq N$ (otherwise, replace $N$ by a larger one).

We have that $a_{n+1}-a_{n}<(l+\varepsilon)(b_{n+1}-b_{n})$ for all
$n\geq N$. Let $n>N$ be arbitrary, we have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & a_{n}-a_{N}\\
 & = & \sum_{k=N}^{n-1}(a_{k+1}-a_{k})\\
 & < & (l+\varepsilon)\sum_{k=N}^{n-1}(b_{k+1}-b_{k})\\
 & = & (l+\varepsilon)(b_{n}-b_{N}).
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}} & < & \frac{a_{N}}{b_{n}}+(l+\varepsilon)(1-\frac{b_{N}}{b_{n}}).
\end{eqnarray*}
It follows that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}} & \leq & \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left\{ \frac{a_{N}}{b_{n}}+(l+\varepsilon)(1-\frac{b_{N}}{b_{n}})\right\} \\
 & = & \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left\{ \frac{a_{N}}{b_{n}}+(l+\varepsilon)(1-\frac{b_{N}}{b_{n}})\right\} \\
 & = & l+\varepsilon.
\end{eqnarray*}
Since $\varepsilon>0$ is arbitrary, we further have $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}\leq l$.

The case that $l=-\infty$ is left to you.